# css - right link in navigation is lower

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

I have problem with right link in my bottom navigation.
This link is a little bit lower.

I am not css specialist, please for help.

My html code:

```
<div class="header container">
    {% if is_paginated %}
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="arrow left"><h4>Previous</h4></a>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="header-label"><h4>Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.</h4></span>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="arrow right"><h4>Next</h4></a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

My css code:

```
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
}
.left {
    left: 0;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring `top` or/and `bottom` values for `.arrow` elements? This will adjust vertical alignment as needed.

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot :) +1